# Is it possible for a phone to still be compromised/infected by malware or spyware even after a factory reset?

Tags: root-access, security, factory-reset, malware, virus

If yes then how can one ensure that its %100 wiped clean?

Android 7 | rooted

EDIT: Same question but how about when rom is flashed
?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's entirely possible if

- the malware/Trojan resides and or modifies `/system` partition ([search would show it's not uncommon](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+malware+in+system+files&oq=android+malware+syste&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0i457j0i22i30l3.17137j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)) .
- Thanks to Firelord who pointed out another possibility of

> cases where an update to system introduced a persistent system level malware (usually a spyware, adware type), or one or two system apps (usually system update apps) acted like a malware right from the time a user started using the device. (see [1](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/android/2020/07/we-found-yet-another-phone-with-pre-installed-malware-via-the-lifeline-assistance-program/), [2](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-53903436), [3](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/03/preinstalled-malware-targets-android-users-of-two-companies/), [4](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/11/chinese-company-installed-secret-backdoor-on-hundreds-of-thousands-of-phones/), [5](https://blog.avast.com/android-devices-ship-with-pre-installed-malware) as examples)

By doing a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset), you are only removing user installed apps and data. The only solution **for the first case** is to install stock ROM (if you are on stock) or install a custom ROM by [clean flash](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132258/131553) (usually, OEMs /custom ROM providers give detailed instructions on this). By installing a ROM, the `/system` is wiped clean and installed, getting rid of the trouble.

If you are a victim of the second case, there isn't much you can do unless you find another ROM for your device.

Of course, you need to review your apps and make sure you don't install from unverified sources and take precautions to not get into this situation again.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is it possible to flash rom through TWRP? If yes, is that considered clean?

Comment: Yes. It is possible depending on the ROM. You will need to wipe `/system ` in addition to `/data ` to flash **but** follow instructions provided by the ROM chef

Comment: Where do I find the "rom chef" instructions for my rom? (Moto C Plus xt1723).

Comment: Xda and other sources like OEM instructions

Comment: So is this a wipe clean (which includes deleting `/system` and `/data`) AND THEN install/flash rom?

Comment: It could be that way or installing itself cleans. Read the instructions. Your question has been answered as asked. If you have doubts on the exact process even after reading it up, please ask a separate question